# am new on coding, and am currently learning python, so am on matplotlib its says attributeerror

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([0, 6])
ypoints = np.array([0, 250])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()

plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the error. Did you install `matplotlib` ?

Comment: On what line said AttributeError did appear?

Comment: You may want to read [ask]